# Не могу скачать SDK через cmd

Tags: android, unity3d, cmd, sdk

В моменте когда я пишу и пытаюсь скачать `sdkmanager "build-tools;31.0.0"` мне выдаёт две ошибки:

Warning: Dependant package with key emulator not found!

Warning: Unable to compute a complete list of dependencies.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причём процесс скачивания останавливается на 10%.

Огромное спасибо за помощь!
У меня windows

Решение: по сути, это не решение данных ошибок, но является альтернативным выходом из положения. Вам нужно скачать sdkmanager.exe прошлых лет, потом установите его и откройте. Там же, вам нужно будет обновить sdkmanager и установить нужные вам компоненты. В случае, если вы не смогли скачать android sdk, то зайдите в tools>bin и скопируйте путь. Откройте командную строку и введите: cd *путь*, потом выберите 'sdkmanager.bat --list' и выберете нужные вам компоненты и скачайте его. Как-то так...

Comment: А можно скрин или типа того?

Comment: Конечно, только что добавил

Comment: https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools
Я тут тока 30ю вижу. Ты точно качаешь то, что существует?

Comment: Да. Я пробовал скачать и прежние версии (как например build-tools 28.0.0 или 25.0.0), но одна и та же ошибка. Для эксперимента, я скачал от сюда: android platform, ndk и ещё некоторые вещи. И что забавно, они устанавливаются без проблем , но вот при скачивании и установки SDK появляется ошибка.

Comment: Как эту хрень себе на комп поставить? Мне гуглить лень. Ща в виртуалке поковыряю. Достаточно поставить android studio?

Comment: Для того чтоб поставить эту хрень, тебе нужно будет зайти на сайт Android Studio и скачать её, а потом тебе нужно будет спуститься ниже до "Command Tools". Тебе нужно будет скачать этот файл и скинуть в папку где ты установил Android Studio (копируешь ссылку на эту папку в файловом проводнике, там где  D:\android...). Заходишь в CMD и пишешь cd: *ссылка*, потом пишешь sdkmanager.bat --list (тебе покажут список), потом выбираешь что тебе нужно, копируешь и пишешь sdkmanager "*то что ты выбрал*" (в моём случае "build-tools;31.0.0". Нажимаешь Enter и начинается загрузка.

Comment: Какую мажорную версию явы надо ставить?

Comment: И кстати, у меня другой путь до сдкменеджера. У меня `appdata\local\android\sdk\tools\bin`. v4.2.2

Comment: У тебя получилось её скачать?  Путь к установленной sdk именно такой, какой ты скинул. Возможно твой компьютер намного мощнее моего, из-за чего у тебя пошло всё без проблем. У меня же (я знаю что всё очень плохо): 2 гб озу, 256 мб видеокарта и процессор 2,75 ггц. Я пробовал скачать её на windows x86 и даже х64, но всё равно одна и та же проблема... чёрт)
Получается, дело в комплектующем компьютера?

Comment: `У тебя получилось её скачать?` Странный вопрос. А в чём проблема-то? ` намного мощнее моего` виртуалка на 2гб озу, win7 pro. Ты так и не ответил про яву. У меня вообще не удалось запустить сдкменеджер. Выдал ошибку явовских кишок. Стоит и 11 и 8. Не помогло.

Comment: Нужно скачать JDK и ещё сделать "JAVA_HOME" и многое другое. Посмотри здесь: https://youtu.be/L-2lZsY90uk

Comment: Я чутка умею ставить юву и про джава_хом в курсе: https://github.com/don-rumata/ansible-role-install-liberica-java

Comment: Вопрос про версию задал не просто так.

Comment: Можно не дебильный видос, где надо смотреть всё "от" и "до", а нормальный туториал, где можно искать по тексту и пролистывать картинки?

Comment: Стоп. СДК не идёт в комплекте с ide? О_о

Comment: В общем УМВР. https://imgur.com/a/oXFVOkj

Comment: Короче, я сделал так: зашёл в google и начал искать sdk manager. Взял версию sdkmanager.exe (2015) и установил её. Потом, через неё я обновил manager и скачал нужные мне компоненты. Что забавно, мадре, нужно было ПРОСТО НАЙТИ НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ УСТАНОВЩИК. Я ПОТРАТИЛ БОЛЕЕ 7-и ДНЕЙ ЧТОБ СКАЧАТЬ SDK, НО ВСЁ БЫЛО ТАК ПРОСТО...

Comment: Переходи на линукс, там установка софта в разы проще.

Comment: Ээээ. Чё искать-то? В гугле первые ссылки. sdk: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip, android studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/